# How can I filter an array and slice an array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

With the following data,

```
// 1
{
    "_id": ObjectId("64a610b3dec8ecf2749147f9"),
    "key": "mini/ttttkey",
    "value": {
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": NumberInt("1"),
                "title": "json-server",
                "author": "typicode"
            },
            {
                "id": NumberInt("2"),
                "title": "json-server111",
                "author": "typicode222"
            }
        ],
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": NumberInt("1"),
                "body": "some comment",
                "postId": NumberInt("1")
            },
            {
                "id": NumberInt("1"),
                "body": "111some comment",
                "postId": NumberInt("1")
            }
        ],
        "profile": {
            "name": "typicode"
        }
    }
}

// 2
{
    "_id": ObjectId("64a611c5177d004d13de7b58"),
    "key": "mini/key1",
    "value": {
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": NumberInt("1"),
                "title": "json-server",
                "author": "typicode"
            },
            {
                "id": NumberInt("2"),
                "title": "json-server111",
                "author": "typicode222"
            },
            {
                "id": NumberInt("2"),
                "title": "json-server111",
                "author": "typicode222"
            }
        ],
        "comments": [
            {
                "body": "some comment",
                "postId": NumberInt("1")
            },
            {
                "body": "111some comment",
                "postId": NumberInt("2")
            }
        ],
        "profile": {
            "name": "typicode",
            "version": "12"
        }
    }
}

// 3
{
    "_id": ObjectId("64a655b4d95c4856e539c9af"),
    "key": "mini/key2",
    "value": {
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": NumberInt("1"),
                "title": "json-server",
                "author": "typicode"
            },
            {
                "id": NumberInt("2"),
                "title": "json-server111",
                "author": "typicode222"
            },
            {
                "id": NumberInt("2"),
                "title": "json-server111",
                "author": "typicode222"
            }
        ],
        "comments": [
            {
                "body": "some comment",
                "postId": NumberInt("1")
            },
            {
                "body": "111some comment",
                "postId": NumberInt("2")
            }
        ],
        "profile": {
            "name": "typicode",
            "version": "12"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to complete the following query:

Question 1: get the filtered array data, like posts field must be `json-server`

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("64a610b3dec8ecf2749147f9"),
    "key": "mini/ttttkey",
    "value": {
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": NumberInt("1"),
                "title": "json-server",
                "author": "typicode"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Question 2: get the limited array data, like just get posts.slice(1,2)

```
// 1
{
    "_id": ObjectId("64a610b3dec8ecf2749147f9"),
    "key": "mini/ttttkey",
    "value": {
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": NumberInt("2"),
                "title": "json-server111",
                "author": "typicode222"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```